# Regular Expression - Remove HTML comment spanning multiple line breaks

Tags: c#, regex, vb.net, replace

I'm using this script:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11902/Convert-HTML-to-Plain-Text

To convert some outlook HTML to plain text.

It nearly works, the only thing that it leaves behind is the CSS which outlook places in html comment tags `<!-- -->` in addition to `<style>` tags (which are removed)

**This is the original text:**

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="Generator" content="Microsoft Word 14 (filtered medium)">
<style><!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
--></style><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapedefaults v:ext="edit" spidmax="1026" />
</xml><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
<o:shapelayout v:ext="edit">
<o:idmap v:ext="edit" data="1" />
</o:shapelayout></xml><![endif]-->
</head>
<body lang="EN-GB" link="blue" vlink="purple">
<div class="WordSection1">
<p class="MsoNormal">tesst<o:p></o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><b><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:dimgray;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB">JOE BLOGS</span></b><span style="font-size:10.0pt;font-family:&quot;Arial&quot;,&quot;sans-serif&quot;;color:dimgray;mso-fareast-language:EN-GB">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**This is the resulting text:** (note the HTML comment has not been removed)

```
<!--
/* Font Definitions */
@font-face
    {font-family:Calibri;
    panose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}
/* Style Definitions */
p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal
    {margin:0cm;
    margin-bottom:.0001pt;
    font-size:11.0pt;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
a:link, span.MsoHyperlink
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:blue;
    text-decoration:underline;}
a:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed
    {mso-style-priority:99;
    color:purple;
    text-decoration:underline;}
span.EmailStyle17
    {mso-style-type:personal-compose;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    color:windowtext;}
.MsoChpDefault
    {mso-style-type:export-only;
    font-family:"Calibri","sans-serif";
    mso-fareast-language:EN-US;}
@page WordSection1
    {size:612.0pt 792.0pt;
    margin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}
div.WordSection1
    {page:WordSection1;}
-->

tesst
&nbsp;
JOE BLOGS
```

I have tried adapting the StripHTML() function with the additional replaces - but these did not work either.

```
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, "(<!--).*?(-->)", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, "<!--*-->", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Please help - this was a 2 minute job that i've been stuck on since lunch *facedesk*

Cheers

**Edit 1**: also tried the following - still no joy

```
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, "<!--.*-->", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
result = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(result, "<!--.*?-->", String.Empty, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

**Edit 2:** I noticed this question was getting a lot of views, anyone reading this should definitely think twice about taking the regExp approach, instead i recommend using Lynx (OpenSource text based browser) to convert HTML to plain text, i asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839225/handle-large-amounts-of-output-from-p-waitforexit-with-redirectstandardoutput) and i provide sample code in the edits based on the answers that should get you started using lynx.exe from within a .net application. This is the method we ended up using and haven't had any problems since.

Comment: It's not really a good idea to use regular expressions to parse HTML. Consider using [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) instead.

Comment: Potentially relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: I couldnt find the converttoplaintext() method in the HTML Agility Pack - have they removed it?

Comment: @HeavenCore: It's still there, in the samples: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94773#1336937

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your second regular expression for three reasons:

- You need to use `.` to match any character.
- The `*` is greedy. You want `*?` to match lazily.
- You need `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

Try this:

```
result = Regex.Replace(result, "<!--.*?-->", "", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

I would strongly recommend that you do not use regular expressions to parse HTML. You will save yourself a whole world of pain if you instead use [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex).

Comment: Sorry Mark, see Edit 1 - neither of those remove the comment section either

Comment: Hi Mark, `<!--.*?-->` + `Singleline` did not work either, i have however took the advise hear and abandoned the reg ex option, i am now working on the HTML Agilty Pack Solution and will update my question if i run into any problems / find the solution.

Comment: Hi Mark, Cheers for pointing me at the sample, that was perfect (table rendering it a little poor but apart from that spot on).

Answer (score 0):

With regards to usage of HTML Agility Pack for this purpose there is a project called  Html2Txt
within the source download under the folder  htmlagilitypack-xxxx\Release\1_4_0\Html2Txt.

The HtmlConvert.cs contains all the necessary functions for converting HTML to Text and taking care of HTML comments etc.